# Java running GUI program from IDE Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm developing a GUI app in JAVA with SWING.
I have a problem when I tried to run the GUI from the Netbeans IDE, Once the GUI is running I'm unable to click or do anything in the interface, in other words, I can't interact with the UI.
For example, when I try to push a button, It does nothing, It's like freezing however it doesn't show any errors and you can close it normally (x icon)
Here's a pic

[image: Netbeans]

Anyone know how to solve this?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64,

java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

javac 1.7.0_75

Here's the code. It's just auto-generated code.

```
public class MainPageAppUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form MainPageAppUI
 */
public MainPageAppUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    DiagnosticoButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    NuevoPacienteButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    PuntoAcupunturaButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    PulsosButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Acupuntura");
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    setEnabled(false);
    setResizable(false);

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jPanel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    DiagnosticoButton.setText("Diagnóstico");
    DiagnosticoButton.setToolTipText("");

    NuevoPacienteButton1.setText("Nuevo Paciente");
    NuevoPacienteButton1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(146, 29));
    NuevoPacienteButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            NuevoPacienteButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    PuntoAcupunturaButton.setText("Puntos Acupuntura");
    PuntoAcupunturaButton.setToolTipText("");

    PulsosButton.setText("Pulsos");
    PulsosButton.setToolTipText("");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(23, 23, 23)
            .addComponent(NuevoPacienteButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(39, 39, 39)
            .addComponent(PuntoAcupunturaButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(44, 44, 44)
            .addComponent(DiagnosticoButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 46, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(PulsosButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(30, 30, 30))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(NuevoPacienteButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(PuntoAcupunturaButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(DiagnosticoButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(PulsosButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 333, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void NuevoPacienteButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    System.out.println("You've pressed Nuevo paciente!");

}                                                    

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPageAppUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPageAppUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPageAppUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPageAppUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainPageAppUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton DiagnosticoButton;
private javax.swing.JButton NuevoPacienteButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton PulsosButton;
private javax.swing.JButton PuntoAcupunturaButton;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The only reason a Swing UI would "freeze" is because you're running some kind of blocking action (like reading from an `InputStream` which is waiting for input) or you have some kind long running loop which is executing from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: I've added the code.
I didn't post it because it is an autogenerated code, I'm using the design view to build the GUI.
I'm not performing any blocking action like you said, I drop some buttons on the panel.
Thanks for taking the time to read and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's extremely unexpected, however, the problem is in your `initComponents` method

```
setEnabled(true);
```

Seems simple enough, but changing it to `setEnabled(false);` solves the problem

Comment: Thanks! It works!, I've to use an external editor, because netbeans doesn't allow to modify the auto generated code

Comment: You can use the form editor and properties editor to change the state of the form ;)